# Securing Prometheus with user id and password

Tags: authentication, ldap, prometheus

I am using Prometheus for monitoring purposes. Now I want it to be secured with LDAP authentication. Currently only the users that have a special role can access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is with a reverse proxy such as Apache or Nginx. Prometheus itself does not support any authentication or authorisation on the serving components.

Comment: Thanks !! But can we specify role over there??